# Problem importing movie as plane

Tags: import

When I import a *.wmv movie using import image to plane in the 2d animation environment, it works correctly. When I attempt to do the same thing in the general workflow setup. the movie doesn't appear. I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.
[image: using 2d workflow]

[image: Using general workflow]

Comment: Are you able to see the movie when switching to "material- or rendered-preview"?

Comment: That did it. The new interface has me a little bit disoriented. Should have thought of that. Thanks, Quacksilber!